# gcc compile and missing header file

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I have an example C file that looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader.h"
#include "myheader2.h"
#include "myheader3.h"

int main() {
int car = 0;
int bike = 0;
int boat = 0;


car = ford;
bike = honda;
boat = corsair;


printf("%d\n",car);
printf("%d\n",bike);
printf("%d\n",boat);

}
```

and three header files located in a folder called headers that look like this
myheader.h:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

#define ford 

#endif
```

myheader2.h:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER2_H
#define MYHEADER2_H

#define honda 1

#endif
```

myheader3.h

```
#ifndef MYHEADER3_H
#define MYHEADER3_H

#define corsair 

#endif
```

and then I use the following command:

```
strace -e write -f gcc -fsyntax-only mymainfile.c -Iheaders
```

and this is the output. In this case, I can see all the errors present until the "end" of the C file.

```
strace: Process 13175 attached
[pid 13175] write(2, "\33[01m\33[Kmymainfile.c:\33[m\33[K In f"..., 62mymainfile.c: In function 'main':
) = 62
[pid 13175] write(2, "\33[01m\33[Kmymainfile.c:12:11:\33[m\33["..., 183mymainfile.c:12:11: error: expected expression before ';' token
   12 | car = ford;
      |           ^
) = 183
[pid 13175] write(2, "\33[01m\33[Kmymainfile.c:14:15:\33[m\33["..., 191mymainfile.c:14:15: error: expected expression before ';' token
   14 | boat = corsair;
      |               ^
) = 191
[pid 13175] +++ exited with 1 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13175, si_uid=1000, si_status=1, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

but if I delete one of the header files and use the same commands on the terminal. Then my output would be like this.

```
strace: Process 13186 attached                                                                                                                                                                          
[pid 13186] write(2, "\33[01m\33[Kmymainfile.c:3:10:\33[m\33[K"..., 198mymainfile.c:3:10: 
fatal error: myheader2.h: No such file or directory                                               
3 | #include "myheader2.h"                                                                                                                                                                
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                          
) = 198                                                                                                                                                                                 
[pid 13186] write(2, "compilation terminated.\n", 24compilation terminated.                                                                                                             
) = 24                                                                                                                                                                                  
[pid 13186] +++ exited with 1 +++                                                                                                                                                       
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13186, si_uid=1000, si_status=1, 
si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---                                                                  
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

is there a way to tell the compiler to "continue" instead of terminating when it can't find a missing header file? that way I can see other errors present on that C file. I'm a noob with compilers. Thanks.

Comment: why do you use strace?

Comment: Normally a missing header is a fatal error because a header, especially a user header, is included because it is **needed** for the program, so its absence means the source file cannot be compiled successfully. I do not think any of the common compilers have a feature for proceeding in the absence of a missing header file. You could get the compiler to proceed either by suppressing the `#include` (by commenting it out or enclosing it in `#if … #endif`) or by replacing the file on disk with an empty file temporarily.

Comment: By using `#if … #endif`, you could make the controlling expression something you can affect from the compile command line, like `#if !defined SuppressHeader`, with which `-DSuppressHeader=1` with GCC or Clang would cause the header not to be included. I doubt you will actually find this useful, as the compilation will typically fail with other problems caused by the missing header.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm working on a script that logs errors when compiling so It's ok if compilation fails at the end as long as I can see all the errors present instead of terminating right away. So if it's a fatal error then I'm assuming it always terminates?

Comment: Re “So if it's a fatal error then I'm assuming it always terminates?”: That is what the “fatal” of “fatal error” means. It kills the compilation.